# fontawesome or glyphicon - for "applications" symbol

Tags: icons, font-awesome, symbols, glyphicons

In one of my html pages I have a menu item called "Applications" under which a few different applications are listed. I wish to use fontawesome or glyphicon (pro) icon beside the menu text "Applications"

Any suggestion on which fontawesome or glyphicon? I haven't been able to find something like this
[image]

which I think represents Applications

Answer (score 0):

This cheatsheet for fontawesome might be of use: https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/